# How can I use a new meteor id when inserting using the meteor mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If I run `meteor mongo` and then in the shell enter

> `meteor:PRIMARY> db.collection_name.insert({field:"string"})`

I get back a document with an ObjectId, but I would like it to have a Meteor id string.

> { "_id" : ObjectId("57e1492daf102b5f83d5e683"), "field":"string" }

I tried this `meteor:PRIMARY> db.dictionary.insert({_id:new Mongo.ObjectId, "field":"string"})` but of course that doesn't work.

How can I insert a document in the mongo shell and give it a unique random id string like it gets when inserted in code?

Like this: `{ "_id" : "xGfyoJE6GBPqG6Av8", "field":"string" }`

Comment: Might be helpful https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3570

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. If that means there is no way to do it, what is a good workaround? I'm thinking of using a text replacement app that might use a random generator. If that were work, what are the chances of getting the same random string that is in the database? I guess it wouldn't matter too much because you could just rerun the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mongo built in method ObjectId() https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

```
db.messages.insert({_id: ObjectId(), "fieldtype": "string"})
```

This will give you what you want